# x86 cmpl and jne

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm tracing some x86 code for an assignment, and I was wondering what exactly "cmpl" does and how to predict whether or not the "jne" will be met.

```
80484bf:    83 7d f0 07             cmpl   $0x7,-0x10(%ebp)
80484c3:    75 16                   jne    80484db
```

Comment: BTW:This is AT&T Syntax.

Answer (score 16):

**[cmpl](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp)**  subtracts -0x10(%ebp) from $0x7 and modifies flags: **AF CF OF PF SF ZF**.

1. If memory at -0x10(%ebp) equals immediate 0x7 then the flag **ZF** is set.  This is below EBP so it's probably a local variable, if this is an un-optimized build using EBP as a frame pointer.
2. **jne 80484db** means that if the two compared numbers are different (ZF=0), jump to  **80484db**

To summarize, your code is equivalent to :

```
compare A to 7
jump to 0x80484db if they are different.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So ZF is set to 0 if -0x10(%ebp) minus $0x7 does not equal zero? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, ZF is set to 0 if -0x10(%ebp) minus $0x7 does not equal

Comment: I think `cmpl` subtracts `$0x7` from `-0x10(%ebp)`, not the other way around (as this looks like AT&T syntax). Shouldn't make a difference here, but it would if the `jne` was a different jump instruction (like `ja`).